# Ant exec: pausing build to accept user input required by executed program

Tags: java, ant

I'm using Ant exec to run a program after my build, the program is a java programm that has a scanner that waits for user input, to choose an option  before it does anything, currently ant exec just runs the program, shows the options and continues with other targets

```
jar:
  [jar] Building jar: /home/me/workspace/app/build/somejar.jar

my.app:
[exec] 
[exec]  Choose one of the following menus 
[exec]  
[exec] 0. Exit 
[exec] 1. do something 
[exec] 2. do something  
[exec] 3. do something amazing 
[exec] 4. do something wonderful 
[exec]  
[exec] 

some.next.target:
```

Comment: Try to nest your operations in `<sequential>yourtasks</sequential>` task. I don't know if it will help but you can try.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the <input> task to get the choice, then pass that along as an input attribute to the <exec> task or use it as an argument for your <exec> task if your program will accept command line arguments.